# Does using `.env` in production have security issues?

Tags: security, environment-variables, production-environment

Does using `.env` in production have security issues? In other word, is it a bad practice to use `.env` files in production?

I remember reading something about this being an issue, but as of today it seems it's not considered as an issue anymore.

Is there caveats in using a `.env` file in production server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, there is no reason to consider the use of `.env` a security issue at all. In fact, the use of `.env` is precisely what many tools (e.g. spinnaker) use to have reproducible environments with specific configuration.

I do use env files to iterate my service from develop to production, having a `.env` file for each stage.